# Loss function in python is a bit cumbersome

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Here is a python function I have for a neural network I have implemented. I feel it become a bit cumbersome. The intention is to weight positive labels in channels `1:end` higher than background pixels. Hence the distinction between foreground and background.

```
def loss_function(
        self,
        x: torch.tensor,
        groundtruth: torch.tensor,
        weight: float
) -> torch.tensor:

    delta = 0.00001
    groundtruth_pos = groundtruth[:, 1:, :, :] == 1
    groundtruth_neg = groundtruth[:, 1:, :, :] == 0
    foreground_gt = groundtruth[:, 1:, :, :]
    background_gt = groundtruth[:, 0, :, :]

    foreground_x = x[:, 1:, :, :]
    background_x = x[:, 0, :, :]
    loss_foreground_pos = -(torch.sum(foreground_gt[groundtruth_pos] * torch.log(foreground_x[groundtruth_pos] + delta))
                            + torch.sum((1 - foreground_gt[groundtruth_pos]) * torch.log(1 - foreground_x[groundtruth_pos] + delta)))
    loss_foreground_neg = -(torch.sum(foreground_gt[groundtruth_neg] * torch.log(foreground_x[groundtruth_neg] + delta))
                            + torch.sum((1 - foreground_gt[groundtruth_neg]) * torch.log(1 - foreground_x[groundtruth_neg] + delta)))

    loss_background = -(torch.sum(background_gt * torch.log(background_x + delta))
                        + torch.sum((1 - background_gt) * torch.log(1 - background_x + delta)))
    return weight * loss_foreground_pos + loss_foreground_neg + loss_background
```

Comment: The code does not compile since it is missing the `import` statements. Here at Code Review we prefer self-contained compilable code snippets that allow us reviewers to run the code with some example data. (This is just a remark for your future questions. Since this question already has an answer, leave the question as it is now.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to calculate the same thing over and over again. Instead of doing this separately for the positive, the negative and all labels (not sure that is the correct word), you could do it once and then use that once you need to calculate the sums:

```
def loss_function(
        self,
        x: torch.tensor,
        groundtruth: torch.tensor,
        weight: float
) -> torch.tensor:

    delta = 0.00001
    foreground_gt = groundtruth[:, 1:, :, :]
    background_gt = groundtruth[:, 0, :, :]
    groundtruth_pos = foreground_gt == 1
    groundtruth_neg = foreground_gt == 0

    foreground_x = x[:, 1:, :, :] + delta
    background_x = x[:, 0, :, :] + delta

    a = foreground_gt * torch.log(foreground_x)
    b = (1 - foreground_gt) * torch.log(1 - foreground_x)
    c = a + b

    loss_foreground_pos = -torch.sum(c[groundtruth_pos])
    loss_foreground_neg = -torch.sum(c[groundtruth_neg])

    loss_background = -torch.sum(background_gt * torch.log(background_x))
                                 + (1 - background_gt) * torch.log(1 - background_x))
    return weight * loss_foreground_pos + loss_foreground_neg + loss_background
```

Note that `sum(a) + sum(b)` is the same as `sum(a + b) = sum(c)`.